# Ubuntu 13.04: Can't login using Ubuntu(Default) session. Stuck in login loop

Tags: gnome-session

When I try to login using Ubuntu(Default) session, I am unable to login. After giving password I am getting this message on screen

```
Unable to launch "gnome-session --session=ubuntu" X session --- "gnome-session -session=ubuntu" not found; falling back to default session.
```

However, I am able to login using Ubuntu Studio Session or Xfce Session or using CTRL+ALT+F1.

I have tried with no success to

- Rename / remove .Xauthority
- Chown username:username .Xauthority
- Using gdm ( I was not able to see login screen after using gdm as
  default and rebooting. I was just seeing blinking cursor)

ls -lah reveals

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username   0 Jan 8 10:39 .Xauthority
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username  38 jan 7 16:17 .xsession
-rw------- 1 username username 418 jan 8 10:39 .xsession-errors
-rw------- 1 username username 418 jan 8 10:39 .xsession-errors.old
```

Contents of .xsession-errors/.xsession-errors.old are as follow

```
Unable to launch "gnome-session --session=ubuntu" X session --- "gnome-session -

session=ubuntu" not found; falling back to default session.
sudo: no tty present and no ask program specified
Script for cjkv statrted at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
Script for cjkv statrted at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
/home/username/.xsession line 1: /usr/bin/gnome-session: Permission denied
```

Permission for /usr/bin/gnome-session are as follow

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 236k Mar 21 3013 /user/bin/gnome-session
```

Please help in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have done all the hard work of diagnosing the issue: `/usr/bin/gnome-session` needs to be executable

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/gnome-session
```

However I strongly advise you to investigate *how* the permission got changed, and whether there are other system files that have been affected.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to log in again. I was in middle of upgrading via terminal then I stopped that. Can you please guide how to investigate about "How the permission got changed" ?

Answer (score 0):

In "-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 236k Mar 21 3013 /usr/bin/gnome-session" the "-rw-rw-rw-" means that nobody can execute `gnome-session`.  It should be "-rwxr-xr-x".  In order to set it to that, do `sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/gnome-session`

If that does not work, the following solves a tremendous number of gnome / X11 / graphics related issues:

`sudo apt-get reinstall --purge ubuntu-desktop`

This will reinstall lightdm and unity and purge their configuration. You can then choose to use gnome 3 instead of unity by selecting it when logging in.

You can also switch from lightdm to gdm by running: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: Thanks for kind response. Did you mean chomod 755 or chown 755 ?

Comment: Chmod! Chown would try to set the owner of that file to the user 755...It might not complete it, as there is usually no user 755, but make sure it is chmod 755..

Comment: Yes, chmod, sorry for the typo.